# Use alarm to set a timeout for reading stdin

Tags: perl, signals, alarm, race-condition

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($timeout, $size, $buffer) = (10, 10, undef);
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm $timeout;
    my $nread = sysread STDIN, $buffer, $size;
    # !!!! race condition !!!!!
    alarm 0;
    print "$nread: $buffer";
};
if ($@) {    
    warn $@;
}
```

Is it correct?
May be there is a race condition between 8 and 9 line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look, what's going on:

```
my ($timeout, $size, $buffer) = (10, 10, undef);
eval {
    #establish ALRM signal handler
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required

    #send alarm signal to program in 10 second
    alarm $timeout;

    #try yo read 10 bytes of data into $buffer
    my $nread = sysread STDIN, $buffer, $size;

    #cancel the previous timer without starting a new one 
    #if we returned from sysread. Yes, if 10 seconds pass
    #before the next function is executed, the script will
    #die even though the data was read
    alarm 0;

    #print number of bytes read (will be 10) and the string,
    #read from input
    print "$nread: $buffer";
};
```

$@ is set if the string to be eval-ed did not compile, or if Perl code executed during evaluation die()d. In these cases the value of $@ is the compile error, or the argument to die:

```
if ($@) {    
    warn $@;
}
```

So, this will print die message "alarm\n" if we didn't return from sysread in 10 second.

In the very unlikely case, when the input will be received just before 10 seconds elapse and we won't be able to run alarm 0;, I suggest to use the following code:

```
my ($timeout, $size, $buffer) = (10, 10, undef);

#I define $nread before the signal handler as undef, so if it's defined
#it means, that sysread was executed and the value was assigned
my $nread = undef;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {

        #if it's not defined - it means, that sysread wasn't executed
        unless(defined($nread))
        {
            die "alarm\n";
        }
    };
    alarm $timeout;
    $nread = sysread STDIN, $buffer, $size;
    alarm 0;
    print "$nread: $buffer";
};
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't save us from the case, when assignment operator wasn't executed.

Links:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html

Comment: After "my $nread = sysread STDIN, $buffer, $size;" and before "alarm 0;". Here!. May be our alarm is elapsed and SIGALARM is delivered.

Comment: @drlexa See it now. Good, that I wrote the careful explanation of what's going on. Investigating the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `alarm` introduces a potential race condition.

The normal solution is to add `alarm 0;` after your `eval` block, so if the first `alarm 0` isn't executed, you could still close the alarm.

Or you can use [Time::Out](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Out/Out.pod) package on CPAN to wrap up your code, it's better and safer.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running this on?  What version of perl?

Works fine for me on Mac OS X 10.8.3 with perl 5.12.4.

If you're using perl on Windows, you'll find that signals don't work the same as on POSIX and POSIX-like operating systems, and you might need to use the 4-argument version of select() instead.